# Set the Key of HashMap to setter

Tags: java

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Double> testMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Double>) sortByValue(commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).getDataUsageCriteria());
```

From above, `testMap` will contains something like `{New=30.0, Previous=70.0}` in ascending order of value so what I want to do is something like below in the if/else loop, as currently I have hardcoded now just to make more sense but I want to use the testMap instead of hardcoding. I want to set `key` as value if condition gets matched `by using key/value pair from map`

```
double percent = r.nextDouble()*100;

if(percent > 1.0 && percent < 70.0(how can I use 70 from testMap instead of hardcoding)) {
//what to put below in place of Previous
    commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).setDataCriteria(Use the Key of 70.0 i.e Previous);
} else if(percent > 71 && percent < 100){
    commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).setDataCriteria(Use the Key of 30.0 i.e New);
}
```

Comment: Will there always be only two key-value pairs in your `Map`? Will adding all the values together always equal 100.0 (e.g., 30.0 + 70.0 = 100.0)?

Comment: @creemama, Yes only two key value pair always summing to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the following may be what you're looking for:

```
final LinkedHashMap<String, Double> testMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
testMap.put("New", Double.valueOf(30.0));
testMap.put("Previous", Double.valueOf(70.0));

// The map contains two entries.
Set<Map.Entry<String, Double>> entries = testMap.entrySet();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Double>> it = entries.iterator();
Map.Entry<String, Double> firstEntry = it.next();
Map.Entry<String, Double> secondEntry = it.next();

Random r = new Random();
double percent = r.nextDouble() * 100;

// percent is a number between 0.0 and 100.0
if (percent < secondEntry.getValue().doubleValue()) // between 0.0 and 70.0 exclusive
{
    commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).setDataCriteria(secondEntry.getKey());
}
else // between 70.0 inclusive to 100.0 (100.0 - 70.0 = 30.0)
{
    commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).setDataCriteria(firstEntry.getKey());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `if(percent > map.get("new") && percent < map.get("previous"))`?  If that's actually what you're asking you should stop at the javadoc for map before going further.

Comment: I can do that way but it will be hard coded. If you look at my question, testMap contains `{New=30.0, Previous=70.0}`. I want to use this testMap in my if else loop.

Comment: @Nevzz03 map has a method `values()` for getting set of values. For key set there is similar method called `keySet()` AFAIR. Use it, iterate ofver it, and you will not have to use hard coded key values

Comment: Can you show me example based on my code. It will be of great help.